# How to add atribute rel=nofollow to Javascript string link

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
var result = str.link("https://www.w3schools.com");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

How to add atribute rel=nofollow for str.link above? And, can i run it for my AMP Page using AMP Javascript Custom? If can, how to do that..

Please, if any body know please answer my above question i appriciate for your answer, thank you.

Comment: [String.prototype.link()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) is deprecated and should not be used

Answer (score 4):

`string.link()` is deprecated and should not be used.  Create an anchor tag element directly like so (and add the `rel` attribute value as well):

```
var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
var result = document.createElement('a');
result.innerText =str;
result.href = "https://www.w3schools.com";
result.rel = "nofollow";
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(result);
```

Comment: It works and is exactly what I expected, Thanks for your answer

Comment: Owh, one again. How to use svg icon on var str as anchor link? Because, when i try it doesn't work the svg icon didn't display